# Understanding the MySQL Engine vs Database Type?

Tags: mysql, database

So I am new to database MySql and Database configuration period.  I originally deployed MySQl with the default Innodb engine and in turn created a database with single table through MySQL workbench.

However, I have decided to change to the MyISAM.  If I changed the default engine to MyISAM, have I made the change to use MyISAM or do I have to recreate the database with the default engine setting changed?

Basically, I created a database with the default engine type of Innodb and want to run a MyISAM DB for my project.

Any help or clarification is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The engine is per table, not per database.

Any tables that you created before changing the default storage engine will need to be converted over to the new type.

Only new tables will use the new default type unless you manually change the old ones.

You can change the storage engine using

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Comment: Well another confusing part of MySQL is that I have always viewed Databases as :  Schema -> Database -> table;   However, with MySQL it is like Schema == Database.  So are you saying you could have Database "X" with a Innodb table and a MyISAM table and on and on?

Comment: Yes, you can.  I have done this before where I was using InnoDB for most of my tables and MyISAM for a few with different requirements.  Both types of tables were in the same database.

Comment: Best of all, you can use all those different table (engine) types in a single query if you want. Join a MyISAM table against an InnoDB table and store the results in a HEAP temporary table - MySQL doesn't care, just as long as the query's correct. The only major time you have to worry about the underlying table type is in a transaction, since some types, like MyISAM, don't support them.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the type of a table to MyISAM using

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ENGINE=MYISAM
```

Note that this will give you an error message if you have defined any foreign keys on the table.

Also, if the table is large, it may take a while, because what MySQL does is create a new table of the chosen type, copy all the data from the old table into it, then delete the old table.

Edit: If you change the default engine, you haven't changed the engime for any tables already created. You have to explicitly change those tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ALTER the table that you created in order for it to be running on MyISAM.

> ALTER TABLE MyTableName ENGINE =
>   MYISAM;